# Initialise thread pool

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

As part of a HW assignment, I'm about to implement a thread pool in ANSI C using pthreads.

I'm having difficulty understanding how to initialise my thread pool. I think the idea is to initialise the pool with thread which sleeps until they get a job to do, however I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Leave out the "pool" part and concentrate on a different issue: How to pass a job to a thread or how to wait for a job within a thread. This is also called a producer-consumer setup. If you have that running, you can just multiply that in order to get a thread pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a queue of jobs (this could be as simple as a linked list), protected by a mutex.  Pair this with a condition variable that is broadcast signalled when a job is added to the queue.  The threads can then wait for a job with code like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_lock);
while (queue_is_empty)
    pthread_cond_wait(&queue_cond, &queue_lock);
job = pop_from_queue();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_lock);
```